# Virus affecting MS Office files

Tags: virus

(I'm not sure if here is correct place for asking this question)

I've come across a strange virus that changed contents of all MS Word, Excel, PowerPoint and image formats. It places this ASCII string in all files:

```
Because fuck you! Thats why
```

How do I recover information?

**Updates**

- This computer is not mine. (I don't use Windows at all). A friend of mine asked me to recover her files. Without those documents she can't get her degree of MSc.
- Modification time of Word files are very close to each other. That's absolutely not the last time the user accessed those files.
- The message is not inserted into body of a document. All contents of the file (binary data) is replaced with an ASCII string. Now they're all 29 bytes in length. This is what I can see in Linux:

  ```
  $ file ./area-research-2013.docx
  ./area-research-2013.docx: ASCII text, with no line terminators
  $ cat ./area-research-2013.docx 
  Because fuck you! That's why.$
  $ stat ./area-research-2013.docx
    File: `./area-research-2013.docx'
    Size: 29              Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
  Device: 821h/2081d      Inode: 2929        Links: 1
  Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ soroush)   Gid: ( 1000/ soroush)
  Access: 2013-05-26 17:32:13.000000000 +0430
  Modify: 2013-05-21 09:51:18.000000000 +0430
  Change: 2013-06-26 17:29:09.870000000 +0430
   Birth: -
  ```
- I don't have any other information about what exactly happened. I got this laptop when a new operating system was installed and everything looks fine right now. This may be a virus, a trojan (running in Java runtime) or an MS Word macro. I'm not interested in what exactly that is and how to get rid of. I'm looking for a way to recover the very important data on one of partitions. If it can help, I'll upload *maybe-infected* executables (7zip-ed).

Comment: I'm curious what makes you believe it's indeed a virus (suggesting it's capable of replication and spreading), and not rather a bit lame office prank by either manually overwriting your documents, or changing them with a fast written custom malware that would do a search of your local MS Office files and attach (inject) this _message_ in their bodies? I'm asking because, well: 1) It seems a bit personal, 2) It could be written really fast, 3) You don't provide any information that would clearly identify this as a computer virus. Have you tried identifying what was changing your files?

Comment: Could you please provide following information: 1) Last modified date stamps for these files (do they change much?), 2) Where in document bodies is this message inserted and how frequently per document? 3) A sample part of the raw document data where it's inserted, 4) List of running processes that you can't identify, 5) Inspect for injected system startup processes using `msconfig` and report names of unidentified applications, 6) Provided you've identified the malware responsible, upload it in an archive to any file sharing service and attach a link to it, so we can inspect it. Thanks!

Comment: For the record, I didn't write your virus no matter how frequently I say that to people.

Comment: @ScottPack - For the record, if this really turns out to be some new yet undiscovered virus, I'd like it named _"know your meme virus"_ ... And I've heard you only write viruses in _Snark++_, is that true? :))

Comment: @ScottPack Why do you feel the need to deny it unless you are guilty of something?

Comment: @TildalWave Shouldn't that be *++Snark*?

Comment: @ScottPack - You have mail! _(in your [DMZ inbox](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9614455#9614455))_ ;)

Answer (score 4):

With this information I am saying the files are overwritten.
So I hope you didn't fool about too much but have a look at file recovery: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=recover+lost+files+windows

If that doesn't work, rewriting the documents will be the only option.
Unless you can find this virus and upload it for analysis :)

Comment: Unfortunately recovering didn't help. I should give this laptop back to its owner today and I can't search anymore. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Better luck next time, sorry to hear about the loss.